# how do you set css to add an asp img?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, stylesheet

how do you set css to add an asp img?

I need to control the size of the image within the div aswell and its alignment? Preferably to the right and make it 15% of the size inside the div?

Any of this possible?

```
div#test {
width:90%; 
z-index:1; 
padding:27.5px; 
border-top: thin solid #736F6E;
border-bottom: thin solid #736F6E;
color:#ffffff;
margin:0 auto;
white-space: pre;
white-space: pre-wrap;
white-space: pre-line;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: This is kind of unclear... when you say 'img' do you mean an `<img>` tag or an Asp.NET `<asp:Image>` control or a background image in "the div"? What is "the div"? Lastly, you name [ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) in the title and body of your question... but then tagged the question [Asp.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) - these are very different technologies.

Comment: Asp.NET <asp:Image> not a background image I need an asp.net image algined to the left of the div and its size compared to the div to be about 15%

Comment: Do you need to _add_ the image or _position_ it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are no.

If you mean an image server control (either `<asp:Image>` or `) CSS is a client-side technology while any Asp.NET server controls are server-side. (keyword: in server controls is server ;) )

If you mean an HTML image (`<img>` with no `runat="server"`) then no again. You'd use JavaScript to do this: CSS cannot add *elements* (things with tags like `<img>`) to the document. It can add text context using the content [property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_gen_content.asp) but not elements like `<img>`.

Lastly, if you mean give "the div" a background image, yes, CSS can do this, using the `background-image` property... but I don't think you can resize background images. Maybe with CSS3... I'm not sure.