# C# (ASP.NET) - Create Images Dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, html

I'm trying to create a Image Dynamically. I got the Link to the Image.

necessary code:

```
foreach (String pictureLink in imageLinks)
{
       Image image = new Image();
       image.ImageUrl = pictureLink;
       imagesDiv.Controls.Add(image);
}
```

But nothing is happens.. How can I do that or what I'm doing wrong?
The Style, of how the pictures should be showed is Googleimagesearch result like..

EDIT:
There is one more thing I would do.. When adding the Placeholders (with the Image), they are showed after all Images where been loaded, but is it possible to add the placeholder with the image, right after it has been added?

Comment: how does an image link look like and in which event handler have you put your code shown above?

Comment: Example, how a link look like: "http://i87.servimg.com/u/f87/13/27/05/11/header10.jpg" without "" and the code executes in the PAGE_LOAD

Comment: I used a Placeholder, it worked fine :D

Comment: Look Edit, for Additional Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this

[Adding asp.net image to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406522/adding-asp-net-image-to-div)

I think it should answer your questions.

Comment: Look Edit, for Additional Problem

Answer (score 0):

Hay, I am to not totally clear on what eMi is try to do but one thing is clear, that is he is trying to download image into an object and then add the object to a control.

We are going start off with a creating an array where all image links will be placed for use.

```
string[] imageLinks= { 
"https://i87.servimg.com/u/f87/13/27/05/11/header10.jpg", "http://pdmakp.gov.pk/Content/img/bg/2.jpg" 
};
```

next step we will created the function which will fetch the image and return it as an Image.

```
public Image DownloadImage(string fromUrl)
        {
            using (System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(fromUrl))
                {
                    return Image.FromStream(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

now the final step is to put both together , from his above example ..

```
 string[] imageLinks= { "https://i87.servimg.com/u/f87/13/27/05/11/header10.jpg", "http://pdmakp.gov.pk/Content/img/bg/2.jpg" };

foreach (String pictureLink in imageLinks)
{
       Image image = DownloadImage(pictureLink);       
       imagesDiv.Controls.Add(image);
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -5):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Types;
using BOO;
using BOFactory;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DAL
{
    public class CustomerDAL:ICustomerDAL
    {
        List<ICustomerBO> emplist = new List<ICustomerBO>();
        List<ICustomerBO> llist = new List<ICustomerBO>();


        public List<ICustomerBO> DBbind()
        {

            string connectionstring = ";


            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_databinding";
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string locn = reader["location"].ToString();
                ICustomerBO loc = new  CustomerBO(locn);
                llist.Add(loc);
            }
            connection.Close();
            return llist;
             }


        public int addemployee(ICustomerBO b)
        {
            string connectionstring = "Server= LENOVO\\SQLEXPRESS, Authentication=Windows Authentication, Database= tempdb";



            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "sp_addemployee";

            command.Connection = connection;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeename", b.empname);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", b.dob);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", b.location);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", b.gender);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doj", b.doj);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@experience", b.experience);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CTC", b.ctc);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", b.designation);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unithead", b.unithead);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectid",b.projectid);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);

            command.Parameters["@id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            int rowaffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();


            connection.Close();

            if(rowaffected>0)
            {
                return rowaffected;
            }

            else
            {
                return 0;
            }                                    
              }

        public bool LOGIN(ICustomerBO l)
        {
            bool flag = false;

            string connectionstring = "Data Source=sql1;" + ";" + "user id=;"
                + "password=tcstvm;";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.CommandText = "sp_loginview";

            command.Connection = connection;

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                string name = reader["UserName"].ToString();
                string pwd = reader["Password"].ToString();

                if((name==l.name)&&(pwd==l.pwd))
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }

             connection.Close();

            return flag;

        }

         public List<ICustomerBO> viewallListBO()
        {

            string ConnectionString = "";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_viewemp7";
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
                string name = reader["employeename"].ToString();
                DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dob"]);
                string locn = reader["location"].ToString();
                string gender = reader["gender"].ToString();
                DateTime doj = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["doj"]);
                int exp = Convert.ToInt32(reader["experience"]);
                int ctc = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ctc"]);
                string desg = reader["designation"].ToString();
                string head = reader["unithead"].ToString();
                int proj =Convert.ToInt32( reader["projectid"]);

                ICustomerBO employee=BOFactory.CustomerBOFactory.ADDEMPLOYEE(id, name, dob, locn, gender, doj, exp, ctc, desg, head, proj);
                emplist.Add(employee);

            }
            connection.Close();
            return emplist;
        }


        public bool EDITCustomer(ICustomerBO bb)
         {
             bool flag = false;
             string ConnectionString = "";

             SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
             connection.Open();
             SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
             command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             command.CommandText = "sp_editemploye";
             command.Connection = connection;
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", bb.id);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeename", bb.empname);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", bb.dob);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", bb.location);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", bb.gender);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doj", bb.doj);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@experience", bb.experience);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ctc", bb.ctc);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", bb.designation);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unithead", bb.unithead);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectid", bb.projectid);
             int rowaffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             connection.Close();
             if (rowaffected > 0)
             {
                 flag = true;
             }
             return flag;
         }

        public bool DeleteEmployee(int bbb)
    {
         bool flag = false;
            string ConnectionString = ;

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "sp_deletemploye";
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", bbb);

            int rowaffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            if (rowaffected > 0)
            { flag = true; }
            return flag;
}


        public List<ICustomerBO> viewallListsearchBO(int exo)
        {
            string ConnectionString = "Data Source = ;" +
              "Initial Catalog = ;"
              + "User id=;"
              + "Password=password;";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", exo);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_searchemployee";
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
                string name = reader["employeename"].ToString();
                DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dob"]);
                string locn = reader["location"].ToString();
                string gender = reader["gender"].ToString();
                DateTime doj = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["doj"]);
                int exp = Convert.ToInt32(reader["experience"]);
                int ctc = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ctc"]);
                string desg = reader["designation"].ToString();
                string head = reader["unithead"].ToString();
                int proj = Convert.ToInt32(reader["projectid"]);

                ICustomerBO employee = BOFactory.CustomerBOFactory.ADDEMPLOYEE(id, name, dob, locn, gender, doj, exp, ctc, desg, head, proj);
                emplist.Add(employee);

            }
            connection.Close();
            return emplist;
        }
    }
}
====================================================================================================================================using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BOO;
using DAL;
using Types;

namespace DALFactory
{
    public class CustomerDALFactory
    {
        public static ICustomerDAL addcustomer()
        {
            ICustomerDAL adddal = new CustomerDAL();
            return adddal;
        }

        public static ICustomerDAL LOGIN()
        {
            ICustomerDAL obj = new CustomerDAL();
            return obj;
        }

        public static List<ICustomerBO>  viewalllist()
        {
            ICustomerDAL cust=new CustomerDAL();
            List<ICustomerBO> cust1 = cust.viewallListBO();
            return cust1;
        }

        public static ICustomerDAL EditCustomer()
        {
            ICustomerDAL d = new CustomerDAL();
            return d;
        }

        public static ICustomerDAL deletecustomer()
        {
            ICustomerDAL e = new CustomerDAL();
            return e;
        }      
        public static List<ICustomerBO> DBBIND()
        {
            ICustomerDAL obj5 = new CustomerDAL();
            List<ICustomerBO> emp1 = obj5.DBbind();
            return emp1;
        }

        public static List<ICustomerBO> viewsearchlist(int exo)
        {
            ICustomerDAL cust = new CustomerDAL();
            List<ICustomerBO> cust1 = cust.viewallListsearchBO(exo);
            return cust1;
        }






        }
}
============================================================================================================================================
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Types;

using BOFactory;
using BLLFactory;
using DALFactory;

namespace miniproject
{
    public partial class AddEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
            if (!IsPostBack)

            {

                ICustomerBLL bllobj1 = BLLFactory.CustomerBLLFactory.dbind();  //dbind();
                List<ICustomerBO> list = bllobj1.dbbind();
                DropDownList5.DataSource = list;
                DropDownList5.DataTextField = "location";
                DropDownList5.DataValueField = "location";
                DropDownList5.DataBind();

            }
        }
        protected void TextBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double a = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text);

            if (a == 0)
            {

                RangeValidator3.MaximumValue = "3";
                RangeValidator3.MinimumValue = "1.5";

                RangeValidator3.Type = ValidationDataType.Double;
                RangeValidator3.Validate();
                if (!RangeValidator3.IsValid)
                {

                    RangeValidator3.ErrorMessage = "Enter CTC between 1.5 and 3";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                double max = (a * 1.5) + 3;
                double min = (a * 1.5) + 1.5;
                RangeValidator3.MaximumValue = max.ToString();
                RangeValidator3.MinimumValue = min.ToString();
                RangeValidator3.Type = ValidationDataType.Double;
                RangeValidator3.Validate();

                if (!RangeValidator3.IsValid)
                {
                    RangeValidator3.ErrorMessage = "Enter CTC between " + min + " and " + max;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string empname = TextBox1.Text;
            DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text);
            string location = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text;
            string gender = RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Text;
            DateTime doj = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text);
            int experience = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text);
            int ctc = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text);
            string designation = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value;
            string unithead = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            int projectid = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);

            ICustomerBLL bllobj = BLLFactory.CustomerBLLFactory.Addcustomer();

            ICustomerBO boobj = BOFactory.CustomerBOFactory.Addcustomer( empname,dob, location, gender, doj, experience,ctc,
             designation, unithead,projectid);

            int rowaffected = bllobj.AddCustomer(boobj);

            if(rowaffected>0)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "call function", "alert('ADDED SUCCESSFULLY.ID=" + rowaffected + "');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('customer not added ')</script>");
            }
           }

        protected void DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void TextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
================================================================================================================================

                           </tr>
                       </table>

  </asp:Content>
========================================================================================================================================================

using Types;
using DALFactory;
using BOFactory;
using BLLFactory;
namespace miniproject
{
    public partial class EditEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                viewdata();
            }
        }
        private void viewdata()
        {
            List<ICustomerBO> emp = DALFactory.CustomerDALFactory.viewalllist();
            GridView1.DataSource = emp;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            viewdata();

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbid = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label1") as Label;

            ICustomerBLL bllobj1 = BLLFactory.CustomerBLLFactory.DeleteEmployee();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(lbid.Text);
            bool rowaffected = bllobj1.deleteemployee(id);
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            viewdata();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            viewdata();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating1(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            GridViewRow SelectedRow = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Label lbid = (Label)SelectedRow.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            string Name = (SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text;
            DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime((SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox).Text);
            string Location = (SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox3") as TextBox).Text;
            string gender = (SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox4") as TextBox).Text;
            DateTime doj = Convert.ToDateTime((SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox5") as TextBox).Text);
            int exp = Convert.ToInt32((SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox6") as TextBox).Text);
            int ctc = Convert.ToInt32((SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox7") as TextBox).Text);
            string Designation = (SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox8") as TextBox).Text;
            string Headid = (SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox9") as TextBox).Text;
            int projid = Convert.ToInt32((SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox10") as TextBox).Text);

            int id = int.Parse(lbid.Text);
            string name = Name.ToString();
            DateTime dob1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dob);
            string locn = Location.ToString();
            string gen = gender.ToString();
            DateTime doj1 = Convert.ToDateTime(doj);
            int expr = Convert.ToInt32(exp);
            int ctc1 = Convert.ToInt32(ctc);
            string desg = Designation.ToString();
            string head1 = Headid.ToString();
            int proj1 = Convert.ToInt32(projid);

            ICustomerBO boobj = BOFactory.CustomerBOFactory.EditCustomer(id, name, dob1, locn, gen, doj1, expr, ctc1, desg, head1, proj1);
            ICustomerBLL bllobj = BLLFactory.CustomerBLLFactory.EditEmployee();
            bool success = bllobj.editemployee(boobj);

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            viewdata();

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow SelectedRow = GridView1.SelectedRow;
            Label lbid = (Label)SelectedRow.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            string Name = (SelectedRow.FindControl("Label2") as Label).Text;
            DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime((SelectedRow.FindControl("Label3") as Label).Text);
            string Location = (SelectedRow.FindControl("Label4") as Label).Text;

            int projid = Convert.ToInt32((SelectedRow.FindControl("Label11") as Label).Text);
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(lbid.Text);

            Session["EmployeeID"] = id;
            Session["EmployeeName"] = Name;

            Session["CTC"] = ctc;
            Session["DESIGNATION"] = Designation;
            Session["HEADID"] = Headid;
            Session["PROJECTID"] = projid;
            Response.Redirect("Update.aspx");
        }
    }
}

==================================================================================================================================
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditEmployee.aspx.cs" Inherits="miniproject.EditEmployee" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceholder1" runat="server">

    <div  style="margin: left:25%">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("empname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("empname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateOfBirth">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dob") %>'></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:CommandField EditText="Select" HeaderText="Action" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField EditText="Delete" HeaderText="Action" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Action" ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
        </div>

</asp:Content>
===================================================================================================================================================================





using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DAL
{
    public class DBUtility
    {
        public static SqlConnection getconnection()
        {

           SqlConnection dbconnection = null;
            ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"];
            if(settings!=null)
            {
                string str = settings.ConnectionString;
                dbconnection = new SqlConnection(str);
            }
            return dbconnection;
        }
    }
}
============================================================================================================================
 public int updatesupplier(ISupplierBO objBO)
     {
         int ret = 0;
         SqlConnection conn = DBUtility.getconnection();
         conn.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.CommandText = "sp_Updatesupplier";
         cmd.Connection = conn;

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplierid",objBO.Suplierid);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Companyname", objBO.Companyname);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contactname", objBO.Contactname);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Companyaddress", objBO.Companyaddress);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", objBO.City);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", objBO.Country);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Homepage", objBO.Homepage);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contactno", objBO.Contactno);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailaddress", objBO.Emailaddress);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bankdetails", objBO.Bankdetails);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accountno", objBO.Accountno);
         ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         conn.Close();

         return ret;

     }

======================================================================================================================================
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=sql01;Initial Catalog=dbtemp;User ID=vishal;Password=mahesh" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
=====================================================================================================================================

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UnitHead">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unithead") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProjectID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("projectid") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Enter ID to search"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageIndex="5" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">



===================================================================================================================================

using Types;
using DALFactory;
using BOFactory;

namespace miniproject
{
    public partial class ViewEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindData();
        }
        private void BindData()
        {
            List<ICustomerBO> emp = DALFactory.CustomerDALFactory.viewalllist();
            GridView1.DataSource = emp;
            GridView1.DataBind();



            }

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text);
            List<ICustomerBO> empc = DALFactory.CustomerDALFactory.viewsearchlist(x);
            GridView2.DataSource = empc;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post an answer consisting of only code, explain your answer!

Comment: Yikes, there 6 lines of code in the question and you respond with 700+ lines of an _entire multi-tier application_?  Surely just copying the relevant, applicable code would have been faster than dumping all of this?

Comment: Short of cutting and pasting the code then doing a find, locating the few lines that address the issue make this answer hard to use.