# Is there a way I can put a link inside a div 

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

Is there a way I can put a link inside a div using c#/css and then create a function in c# asp.net to delete that div?

Im looking to add **Delete** to the top right hand corner of my div which is like a link then in my code behind call a function which will delete that entry from my database.

My css:

```
div .test
{
  width:90%; 
  z-index:1; 
  padding:27.5px; 
  border-top: thin solid #736F6E;
  border-bottom: thin solid #736F6E;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin:0 auto;
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

EDIT:
Nothing is being rendered so far on the page:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    div.Attributes["class"] = "test";
                    div.ID = "test";


                    // Deletebutton div with link
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divClose = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    divClose.Attributes["class"] = "deleteButton";
                    divClose.ID = "deleteButton";
                    div.Controls.Add(divClose);
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl link = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    link.ID = "link";
                    divClose.Controls.Add(link);

                    Image img = new Image();
                    img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(1));
                    img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                    div.Controls.Add(img);
                    div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0))));
                    div.Style["clear"] = "both";

                    test1.Controls.Add(div);
```

css:

```
div#test1 {
}
div .test {
  width:90%; 
  z-index:1; 
  padding:27.5px; 
  border-top: thin solid #736F6E;
  border-bottom: thin solid #736F6E;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin:0 auto;
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.deleteButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.deleteButton a{
  display:none;
}

.deleteButton:hover a{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to [the question you asked a few days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406286/how-do-you-set-css-to-add-an-asp-img/5406444). You need to do some reading about the difference between server-side and client-side as well as the separation of concerns between HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML create the link. We will hide it using css, and display it when we hover the div.

```
<div class="deleteButton">
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="delButton" Text="Delete"/>
</div>
```

If you create the div in Code:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.Attributes["class"] = "test";
div.ID = "test";


// Deletebutton div with link
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divClose = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
divClose.Attributes["class"] = "closeButton";
divClose.ID = "closeButton";
div.Controls.Add(divClose);
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl link= new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("a");
link.ID = "link";
divClose.Controls.Add(link);

img = new Image();
ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(1));
img.AlternateText = "Test image";

div.Controls.Add(img);
div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0))));
div.Style["clear"] = "both";

test1.Controls.Add(div);
```

This is the CSS used to hide/display the link.

```
<!-- CSS -->
.deleteButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.deleteButton a{
  display:none;
}

.deleteButton:hover a{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: thats cool like the hover idea could you help some more, I forgot to mention the divs are dynamically assigned? So they dont exist on my asp page untill a use types something in my textbox then it will be displayed on the page under my css code above!

Comment: There is no difference if they are dynamically created or not. just let them have the appropriate classname through the code behind. I edited my post so you can play around with it some more.

Comment: each text the users writes and hits the button is added under a new div called test i need each of these "div id=test" to hold there own link deletebutton so they can be deleted individually

Comment: in your code behind, you need to create this div every time the user clicks the button, and put it inside the "div id=test".

Comment: atm your code isnt working, it is there if I look at it from firebug and i inspect the element but nothing is shown on the page

Comment: Ahh I see what you have done, you have only added another div, you didnt actually add the button in the code behind.

Comment: Yes, you add the other DIV with the LinkButton in code behind, and it *should* be shown when you go over it with your mouse. I didn't test the code, i just typed it from mind. I do hope I gave you an idea on how to solve your problem. If you need more info, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot create links. You have to build them in your HTML.